# My PHP contact form is showing the server address to the submitter mail and copy to is not working

Tags: php, contact-form

everyone,
I am using a .php script for contact process. It is working fine. But I need help for two very minor things. I have tried my level best by googleing but all went in vein.

The script is

```
<?php


/* Subject and Email variables */


$emailSubject = 'sales';
$email_to = 'ritwikmojumder@gmail.com';


/* Gathering data variables */


$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$contactField = $_POST['contact'];
$emailField = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$chooseserviceField = $_POST['chooseservice'];
$commentsField =$_POST['comments'];


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Name: $nameField<br>
Contact No: $contactField<br>
Choose Service: $chooseserviceField<br>
Comments: $commentsField<br>
EOD;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$success = mail($email_to,$emailSubject,$body,$headers);


//These are the variables for the email

$sendto = $_POST['emailaddress']; // this is the email address collected form the form
$ccto = "amitabh197@gmail.com"; //you can cc it to yourself
$subject = "WebBrahma"; // Subject
$message = "Dear Customer,


We have received your e-mail.Thank you for writing to us.


We shall revert to your Query within 48 hours.


Should we require more time for further Co ordination, we will keep you 
informed. 


Assuring you of our best services.


Note: This is an auto generated message.


Warm Regards,
Billing|WebBrahma 
033-65360954


Incase you don't hear from us, escalate by writing to us at escalate@webbrahma.com
";


$header = "From: <ritwikmojumder@gmail.com>";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";


// This is the function to send the email
mail($sendto, $subject, $message, $header); 


/* Results rendered as HTML */


$theResults = <<<EOD
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Web Hosting | Your friendly Web Hosting Company</title>


<link href="css/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Telex' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gravitas+One|Paytone+One|Radley|Ultra|Bowlby+One|Prata|Spinnaker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-stuff/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gravitas+One|Paytone+One|Radley|Ultra|Bowlby+One|Prata|Medula+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<!-- Hook up the FlexSlider -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
</script>


<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// initialise plugins
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
});


function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x; if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}


function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>



</head>


<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/readmorebtn1.png','images/face1.png','images/twitter2.png')">


<div id="wraper"> <!--start of "wraper"-->
<div id="header">
<div id="headertop">
<div style="height:27px;"></div> <!--blankdiv-->
<div class="logologin">
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="loginbox">
<ul>
<li style="margin-top:-30px; "><iframe src="chat.html" style="width:350px; height:250px; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- End of "loginbox"-->
</div><!--End of "logologin"-->

<div style="height:15px;"></div> <!--blankdiv-->
<div id="nav"> <!--navigation tabs-->

<div id="nava">
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li class="current">
<a href="index.html"><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Home</span></strong></a>

<li class="current">
<a href="aboutus.html"><span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:-12px;"><strong>Company</span></strong></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:-12px;"><strong>Services</strong></span></a>
<ul>
<li style="font-size:95%;"><a href="webdesigning.html">Web Designing</a></li>
<li><a href="hosting.html">Web Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="internetmarketing.html">Internet Marketing</a></li>
<li style="font-size:95%;"><a href="technicalconsultancy.html">Technical Consulting</a></li>
<li><a href="http://webbrahma.supersite.myorderbox.com/domain.php
" target="_blank">Domain Booking</a></li>
<li><a href="webmaintenance.html">Web Maintenance</a></li>
<li style="font-size:95%;"><a href="#">Content Management</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="contact.html"><span style="font-size:18px; margin-left:-12px;"><strong>Contact</strong></span></a>

</li>
</li>
</ul>



</div><!--End of "nava"-->




<div id="navb"><span style="margin-left:420px; font-family:'Telex', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:100%; position:absolute; margin-top:15px;"><span style="font-size:24px; color:#000;">✆:</span> 9088016369</span></div>
<br class="clearfloat" />



</div> <!-- End of "navigation"-->

</div><!--End of "headertop"-->

<div id="container1"><!--Start of "container"-->

<div style="height:35px;"></div><!--Blank Div"-->

<div id="jquerybase">


<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
<img src="images/banner1.jpg" />

</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="images/banner2.jpg"/></a>

</li>
<li>
<img src="images/banner6.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/banner5.jpg"/>
</li>

<li>
<img src="images/banner3.jpg"/>
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/banner4.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img src="images/banner7.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div> <!--End of "flexslidfer"--->
<div></div>
<!--<div id="search">
<div id="searcha"><img src="images/search.png" width="213" height="73" /></div>
<div id="searchb">
<div class="box1"><p>www.</p></div>
<div class="box2">
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="350"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">


<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="" class="comtxt"/>

<label for="select"></label>
<select name="select" class="com" id="select">
<option>.com</option>
<option>.in</option>
<option>.net</option>
<option>.org</option>
</select>

</form></td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>

</div>
<div id="searchc"><img src="images/transfer.png" width="167" height="38" style="float:right;"/></div>


</div><!--End of "search"-->





</div><!--End of "jquerybase"--->

</div> <!--End of "container1"-->

</div> <!-- End of "header"-->



<div style="height:119px;"></div> <!--blank div-->


<div id="container2">

<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left"><img src="images/logo.png" width="252" height="57" style="margin-left:20px;"/>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;<font face="Trebuchet MS" size="5"><b>Thank you.</b></font></p><br /><br />
<p align="center">&nbsp;<font face="Trebuchet MS" size="5"><b>We will get back to you in 48 hrs.</b></font></p>





<!-------------------------- "tab1" starts here------------------------------->
<!-- End of "tab1"-->


</div> <!--End of "container2"-->

<!--------------------------------"extralinks" i.e. bottom links---------------------->
<div id="extralinks">

<div id="container3">


<div id="container3left" style="width:200px; margin-left:40px;">

<ul style="width:200px;">

<li><a href="domains.html" onclick="return openWindow(this, {width:400,height:250,center:true})">Domains &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="webdesigning.html">Web Designing &raquo; </a></li>
<li><a href="hosting.html">Web Hosting &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="webmaintenance.html">Web Maintenance &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>



</div> <!---End of "container3left"---->
<div id="container3mid" style="width:200px; margin-left:40px;">


<ul style="width:200px;">

<li><a href="seo.html">SEO &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="socialmediamarketingservices.html">Social Media Marketing &raquo; </a></li>
<li><a href="linkbuilding.html">Link Building &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="ppc.html">PPC Management Services &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>


</div><!---End of "container3mid"---->
<div id="container3right" style="width:200px; margin-left:40px;">

<ul style="width:200px;">

<li><a href="onlinepromotion.html">Online Promotion &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="technicalconsultancy.html">Technical Consulting &raquo; </a></li>
<li><a href="contentmanagment.html">Content Management &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="feedsubmissionservices.html">Feed Submission &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>


</div><!---End of "container3right"---->
<div id="container3right" style="width:200px; margin-left:40px;">

<ul style="width:200px;">
<li><a href="emailmarketing.html">Email-Marketing &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Home &raquo;</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us &raquo; </a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>


</div><!---End of "container3right"---->
</div> <!--end of "extralinks"--->


<!------------------------Footer------------------------------>

<div id="footer">

<div id="container4">

<div id="container4left">



<p>
Rights Reserved to <strong style="color:#F30;">WebBrahma</strong></p><br/>
<p>Designed By: <a href="www.damiracle.com"><strong>Da Miracle</strong></a></p>

</div>
<div id="container4mid">
<ul id="menu-jquery" style="margin-left:50px;">
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/WebBrahma/284395434959118" target="_blank"><img src="images/677166248.png" width="35px" height="35px" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/iWebBrahma" target="_blank"><img src="images/twit.png" width="35px" height="35px" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/103440980890044057050/" target="_blank"><img src="images/google-Plus-icon.png" width="35px" height="35px" /></a></li>
<li><a href="https://webbrahma.com/blog" target="_blank"><img src="images/wordpress1.png" width="35px" height="35px" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>





</div> <!--End of "container4"-->




</div> <!-----End of "footer"------------------>
</div> <!--End of "wraper"-->
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";

?>
```

Here, I am finding all are working fine. But my problems are 
1. When a submitter is submitting a query he is receiving an acceptance mail to him. But in his mail it is showing in the header part ***" via.vps.dial4solution.com" (which is my server)***  and that is awkward for me.
So, I need to get rid off this problem where the via.vps.dial4solution.com shall not show. In this regard I have tried hard to change by all possible means in the script but it didn't worked. Please help.

1. When the submitter is submitting I need to get a cc mail of that  query. I have scripted there

**$ccto = "amitabh197@gmail.com";**

But the cc mail I am not receiving.

Please help me to get rid of all these problems.
Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: You know you have `$header` and `$headers` right? Also why are you adding all that html to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$header = "From: <ritwikmojumder@gmail.com>";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers = "From: <ritwikmojumder@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: <amitabh197@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

Notice the 's' in the first `$headers`, the "\r\n" after the `From:` header and the new `Cc:`header.

Comment: Thanks geon but still now the cc mail is not coming. and astonishingly   instead of via@vpssolution    Nobody nobody@vps.dial4solution.com is coming in the submitter's mail. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing email headers manually, try using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class library. I had many similar special needs and had good experiences with this package.